# System.Diagnostics.Process Exit Code is 0xc0000005 instead of 0 on one specific machine

Tags: c#, process, c++-cli, mapi

I'm stumped...

We have an old 32 bit application that is launching a 64 bit stub application to send email via Outlook 64, using MapiEmail::Email::SendMail. I should be getting 0 or 1 back from the stub as the Process Exit Code, but on one laptop we're getting 0xC0000005 back.. even though it is still successfully sending the email.

If I comment out the SendMail line in the stub I get the expected ExitCode of 0. Also if I display the result of SendMail in the stub (via System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show), the ExitCode as reported by Process::ExitCode also ends up being 0.

I know I could ditch this entirely and just rely on some sort of return file getting written.. but would love to understand what's going on and if there's a way to more easily address it. For example, I'm hoping there's a magic setting that will force the exit code to be what our [Main] method returns, regardless of whatever the OS later on wants it to be.

Here's the primary method in the stub:

```
bool SendMailInterop::SendEmail(std::string & name, std::string & from, std::string & to, std::string & cc, std::string & subject, std::string & body, std::string & attachment)
{
    String^ result = "";
    try
    {
        MapiHelper::InitializeMapi();

        String^ _name = gcnew String(name.c_str());
        String^ _from = gcnew String(from.c_str());
        String^ _to = gcnew String(to.c_str());
        String^ _cc = gcnew String(cc.c_str());
        String^ _body = gcnew String(body.c_str());
        String^ _subject = gcnew String(subject.c_str());
        String^ _attachment = gcnew String(attachment.c_str());

        Email^ email = gcnew Email();

        result = email->SendEmail(_name, _from, _to, _cc, _subject, _body, _attachment);

        //Interesting. If I do the following, the ExitCode of the System.Diagnostics.Process object
        //we use to invoke this stuff is correctly 0. If I leave it commented out, we'll get 0xC0000005
        //in the one test laptop 
        //System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(result) 

        delete email;

        MapiHelper::UninitializeMapi();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
    return (result == "OK [0]");
}
```

Here's the invoking code (our app is C++, calling this C# via interop)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process sendEmail64 = new Process();
            sendEmail64.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            sendEmail64.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            sendEmail64.StartInfo.FileName = stubExePath;
            sendEmail64.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"""{0}""", file);
            sendEmail64.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            sendEmail64.Exited += new EventHandler(SendEmail64_Exited);
            sendEmail64.Start();
:
Some hacky wait looping
:
MessageBox.Show("exit code: 0x" + sendEmail64.ExitCode.ToString("X"));
```

Comment: That error code means there's an access violation. Somehow, somewhere in the C++ code, you're dereferencing an invalid pointer

Comment: There's classic UB symptoms here but we have no chance of diagnosing them from here, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since the common Office runtime (licensing, performance monitoring, etc.) was moved into the MAPI system (the common MSO runtime gets initialized when you call `MAPIInitialize`), if you app exits quickly enough, MSO runtime does not have enough time to completely initialize when it attempts to shut down, resulting in a crash.

MS is working on a fix, which should be available soon.

Comment: Got it, thanks. In the meantime this is a production issue for us. Would it do to put in an artificial delay after the SendMail call to give it some time? Or is there a way to tell when the initialize is fully done?

Comment: Following up with results of an experiment.. a one second delay wasn't enough; 5 was.

Comment: Can you try the Insider Fast/Beta version of Outlook and see if the problem is still there?

Comment: I'll try, but honestly i'm not sure what Microsoft is doing these days. Personally I'm using a Mac with Mac Outlook.  The PC in question is brand new from Best Buy - An HP Envy - bought to repro another issue. It came with some version of Microsoft 365, but I couldn't get Outlooked licensed with any license from my MSDN subscription. Eventually I convinced it to license with Outlook 2019.. so the splash screen comes up as Outlook 365 but the About box says it's Outlook 2019. Whatever it is.. it works. Just not sure if it's eligible for beta per https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows.